# Is H2O target mean encoding available in Python?

Tags: python, h2o

I noticed H2O has released the target mean encoding

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html

It only comes with an R code example. Does anyone have a Python example?

Comment: For your future convenience please note that documentation that you have provided link to comes with both R and Python code examples. Please look for a toggle above code snippets. Toggles work page-wise so it is possible to change language with just one click on any of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
from h2o.targetencoder import TargetEncoder

# Fit target encoding on training data
targetEncoder = TargetEncoder(x= ["addr_state", "purpose"], y = "bad_loan", fold_column = "cv_fold_te")
targetEncoder.fit(ext_train)
```

But this requires version at least 3.22

Here is a link to an example: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/78c3766741e8cbbbd8db04d54b1e34f678b85310/best-practices/feature-engineering/feature_engineering.ipynb

And the link to code itself: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/targetencoder.py

Comment: can you share me the link about where you find the example? I didn't find in H2O document

Comment: Sure. It is "hidden", but I have found it some time ago: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/78c3766741e8cbbbd8db04d54b1e34f678b85310/best-practices/feature-engineering/feature_engineering.ipynb And the link to code itself: https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/targetencoder.py

Comment: have you tested the Python code for target encoder? I some some error using the sample code https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55306686/h2o-target-mean-encoder-frames-are-being-sent-in-the-same-order-error

Comment: @Gavin issue is fixed and should be available in the next fix release 3.24.0.3