# can H2O target mean impute output the mapping table for each level of categorical variable?

Tags: python, h2o

I am learning the H2O TargetEncoder function from h2o.targetencoder. I am wondering, is there a way that we can export the mapping table for each level of the categorical variable?

For example, if we have 2 categorical variable for 50 US states and 5 weekdays. Can TargetEncoder export a results table with the mapped numeric value for the 50 states and 5 weekdays?

Comment: In this [tutorial](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/target-encoding.html#perform-target-encoding), a variable named `te_map` is returned by the function `h2o.target_encode_create()`. Have you tried looking at the `te_map` variable and does it have the information you're looking for?

Comment: that is R code, is there a Python example?

Comment: The examples [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54102766/is-h2o-target-mean-encoding-available-in-python) don't explicitly say it, however we can see in the [source code](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/blob/master/h2o-py/h2o/targetencoder.py) that `targetEncoder.fit(ext_train)` returns a mapping.

Comment: yes, I saw there it can return _encodingMap. It is a h2o.expr.H2OCache object. I am still not sure how to get the mapping table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on the example [here](https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-tutorials/blob/78c3766741e8cbbbd8db04d54b1e34f678b85310/best-practices/feature-engineering/feature_engineering.ipynb), you can access the mapping after calling `targetEncoder.fit(ext_train)` with:

```
encodingMapFramesKeys = list(map(lambda x: h2o.get_frame(x['key']['name']), targetEncoder._encodingMap.frames))

encodingMapFramesKeys[0].describe()
encodingMapFramesKeys[1].describe()
```